# converting txt file from bash command line

Tags: bash, text, sed

if I have a txt file with an item in each line for example, fruits.txt.

```
apples
oranges
bananas
cherries
```

How can I use a **bash** command line/s to convert it into another txt file that has an enumerated id corresponding to a particular fruit, to say fruitids.txt.

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'apples'
}

item {
  id: 2
  name: 'oranges'
}

item {
  id: 3
  name: 'bananas'
}

item {
  id: 4
  name: 'cherries'
}
```

Comment: you can do it with awk,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

`nl fruits.txt |awk '{print "item {\n" "\t id:" $1"\n \t name:" $2 "\n}"}' > fruitsid.txt`

Answer (score 2):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ printf "item {\n  id: %d\n  name: \047%s\047\n}\n",NR,$1 }' fruits.txt > fruitids.txt
```

The final `fruitids.txt` contents:

```
item {
  id: 1
  name: 'apples'
}
item {
  id: 2
  name: 'oranges'
}
item {
  id: 3
  name: 'bananas'
}
item {
  id: 4
  name: 'cherries'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with pure `bash`:

```
c=0
while read i; do 
    c=$((c+1))
    echo -e "item {\n  id: $c \n  name: '$i'\n}"
done < <(cat fruits.txt) >> fruitsid.txt
```

One-liner:

```
c=0; while read i; do c=$((c+1)) && echo -e "item {\n  id: $c \n  name: '$i'\n}" ; done < <(cat fruits.txt) >> fruitsid.txt
```

Output:

```
item {
  id: 1 
  name: 'apples'
}
item {
  id: 2 
  name: 'oranges'
}
item {
  id: 3 
  name: 'bananas'
}
item {
  id: 4 
  name: 'cherries'
}
```

Comment: bash one-liners are really hard to read: please add some newlines